# XLNetTokenizer requires the SentencePiece library but it was not found in your environment

Tags: google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to implement the XLNET on Google Collaboratory. But I get the following issue.

```
ImportError: 
XLNetTokenizer requires the SentencePiece library but it was not found in your environment. Checkout the instructions on the
installation page of its repo: https://github.com/google/sentencepiece#installation and follow the ones
that match your environment.
```

I have also tried the following steps:

```
!pip install -U transformers
!pip install sentencepiece

from transformers import XLNetTokenizer
tokenizer = XLNetTokenizer.from_pretrained('xlnet-base-cased-spiece.model')
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After the 
!pip install transformers and
!pip install sentencepiece 
please restart your runtime and then execute all other codes.

Comment: Yes, it works, but I get this message "Calling XLNetTokenizer.from_pretrained() with the path to a single file or url is deprecated"

Comment: Try this --> (1) from transformers import TFXLNetModel, XLNetTokenizer      (2) xlnet_model = 'xlnet-large-cased'    (3) xlnet_tokenizer = XLNetTokenizer.from_pretrained(xlnet_model)

Comment: Perfect. It works. Thank you @  Anoop kottappuram

Comment: it doesn't work on windows, i did exactly the same

Comment: I tried `pip install simpletransformers` instead and it worked for my case.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error in google colab. Restarting the runtime did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the runtime in colab did it for me. like the one mention aboved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).